Golang socks5 proxy with traffic limit forwarding to the next socks5 proxy
The first socks5 proxy with traffic limit, the next socks5 proxy without any limit.
Use curl download something like:
curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:10801 -O https://mirrors.xxxx.iso
At first, curl downloads fine, the traffic limit is working, but after while curl speed becomes 0.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/juju/ratelimit"
    "io"
    "net"
)

var nextProxy = "127.0.0.1:10802"

func main() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":10801")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Listen failed: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    for {
        client, err := server.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Accept failed: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        go handle(client)
    }
}

func handle(conn net.Conn) {

    // add close
    defer conn.Close()

    // next socks5 proxy
    nextConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", nextProxy)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to connect to next proxy:", err)
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    defer nextConn.Close()

    go func() {
        _, err := Copy(nextConn, conn)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error copying data to next proxy:", err)
            conn.Close()
        }
    }()

    _, err = Copy(conn, nextConn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error copying data from next proxy:", err)
        conn.Close()
    }
}

func Copy(left io.Writer, right io.Reader) (int64, error) {
    
    right = ratelimit.Reader(right, ratelimit.NewBucketWithRate(102400, 102400))

    return io.Copy(left, right)
}


I've tried another Copy like:
func copyWithRateLimit(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader, limiter *ratelimit.Bucket) {
    // buffer
    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024) // 32KB buffer
    for {
        n, err := src.Read(buf)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("Error reading from source:", err)
            return
        }

        // Rate limit the data
        if limit := limiter.WaitMaxDuration(int64(n), time.Second); !limit {
            fmt.Println("Error rate limiting:", err)
            return
        }

        if _, err := dst.Write(buf[:n]); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing to destination:", err)
            return
        }
    }
}

Even if you increase the buffer to 64*1024, the speed still goes to 0 and eventually it doesn't work.

There is the next socks5 proxy without traffic limit like:
package main

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":10802")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Listen failed: %v\n", err)
        return
    }

    for {
        client, err := server.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Accept failed: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        go process(client)
    }
}

func process(client net.Conn) {
    if err := Socks5Auth(client); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("auth error:", err)
        client.Close()
        return
    }

    target, err := Socks5Connect(client)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("connect error:", err)
        client.Close()
        return
    }

    Socks5Forward(client, target)
}

func Socks5Auth(client net.Conn) (err error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 256)

    n, err := io.ReadFull(client, buf[:2])
    if n != 2 {
        return errors.New("reading header: " + err.Error())
    }

    ver, nMethods := int(buf[0]), int(buf[1])
    if ver != 5 {
        return errors.New("invalid version")
    }

    n, err = io.ReadFull(client, buf[:nMethods])
    if n != nMethods {
        return errors.New("reading methods: " + err.Error())
    }

    n, err = client.Write([]byte{0x05, 0x00})
    if n != 2 || err != nil {
        return errors.New("write rsp: " + err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}

func Socks5Connect(client net.Conn) (net.Conn, error) {
    buf := make([]byte, 256)

    n, err := io.ReadFull(client, buf[:4])
    if n != 4 {
        return nil, errors.New("read header: " + err.Error())
    }

    ver, cmd, _, atyp := buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]
    if ver != 5 || cmd != 1 {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid ver/cmd")
    }

    addr := ""
    switch atyp {
    case 1:
        n, err = io.ReadFull(client, buf[:4])
        if n != 4 {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid IPv4: " + err.Error())
        }
        addr = fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", buf[0], buf[1], buf[2], buf[3])

    case 3:
        n, err = io.ReadFull(client, buf[:1])
        if n != 1 {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid hostname: " + err.Error())
        }
        addrLen := int(buf[0])

        n, err = io.ReadFull(client, buf[:addrLen])
        if n != addrLen {
            return nil, errors.New("invalid hostname: " + err.Error())
        }
        addr = string(buf[:addrLen])

    case 4:
        return nil, errors.New("IPv6: no supported yet")

    default:
        return nil, errors.New("invalid atyp")
    }

    n, err = io.ReadFull(client, buf[:2])
    if n != 2 {
        return nil, errors.New("read port: " + err.Error())
    }
    port := binary.BigEndian.Uint16(buf[:2])

    destAddrPort := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", addr, port)
    dest, err := net.Dial("tcp", destAddrPort)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New("dial dst: " + err.Error())
    }

    n, err = client.Write([]byte{0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0})
    if err != nil {
        dest.Close()
        return nil, errors.New("write rsp: " + err.Error())
    }

    return dest, nil
}

func Socks5Forward(client, target net.Conn) {

    forward := func(src, dest net.Conn) {
        defer src.Close()
        defer dest.Close()

        io.Copy(src, dest)
    }

    go forward(client, target)
    go forward(target, client)
}



Launching both programs on the same machine and curl downloading the file gives the following result:

Did a few tests.

Set the first proxy to have the same bandwidth as the machine, and curl downloads the file normally.
curl downloads only through the second socks5 proxy, and set a speed limit on the second socks5 proxy, curl downloads the file normally.
Both the first proxy and the second proxy set the same traffic limit, and curl downloads the file is ok!!!


I think Copy itself doesn't have a problem. It limited the intended limit. I check it at my local machine (https://go.dev/play/p/5a-T4tIaEFC). How about checking your proxy or mirrors server setting? Or, please give me a code that I can run at my local machine, to look into it.

How much of the file is being transferred? With io.Copy "A successful Copy returns err == nil", and your code does not close conn if nil is returned, which will leave curl with an open connection to your "proxy" (note this does not look like a SOCKS5 proxy).

@nimdrak I added the source code for both services and curl downloads different files all with the same problem.

@Brits I added conn.Close but the problem persists, I'm wondering if it's a buffer issue

@JackyLam I tested your code again. (1) go run ./sock5.go (your second code) at a terminal (2) go run ./rate_limit.go (your first code) with Copy of rate:102400 and capacity:102400, at another terminal. And then curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:10801 -O https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-2009.iso at the other terminal. It seems to work well.

When I use copyWithRateLimit instead of Copy, it seems to work well too. I think there is no problem in your code.

The Current Speed is not zero for a long time.

@nimdrak Thank you very much for your help. It might be the internet environment on my side. I added double bandwidth limitation which solved the problem temporarily.

Good to hear that! I summarized our conversation in the anwer. If you're okay, please accept it :bow:

I checked the below things. I think there is no problem in your code itself. So I decided your environment can be one of the possible causes.
(1) Copy function itself works well. I checked it by using this code. https://go.dev/play/p/5a-T4tIaEFC
(2) Using your added code for sock5 proxy, I checked it works well too.

a. go run ./sock5.go (your second code) at a terminal
b. go run ./rate_limit.go (your first code) with Copy of rate:102400 and capacity:102400, at another terminal.
c. And then curl -x socks5://127.0.0.1:10801 -O https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-2009.iso at the other terminal.

